# Log every request in Helidon

Tags: helidon

I want to log something on every incoming request and then I used the .any() method in the routing and placed the logger there. However, this ruined the 404 not found behaviour. Is there another way to do this sort of enter/exit methods properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to handle such “filter” like stuff, you should call `req.next()` - this will tell the server there is another handler. If nothing is found, `404` is returned as expected

```
Routing.builder()
  .any((req, res) -> {
    System.out.println(“Request: ” + req.path());
    req.next();
  })
  .get(“/”, (req, res) -> res.send(“Hello World”))
.build();
```